# Remote Handle Exception in Jmeter

Tags: exception, jmeter

I am working on the app which was tested using LoadRunner Ajax TruClient Protocol in the past.We are migrating the scripts to JMeter where we are receiving the error on one of the call ending with processfieldSelect.dwr. Response of all the previous requests are expected and the required correlations are done.

> Exception : dwr.engine._remoteHandleException('0','0',{javaClassName: "java.lang.Throwable", message:"Error"})

required validation are done prior to the failed request.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So you either need to simulate the required AJAX request(s) using [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)(s) or go for [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework, it will be the equivalent of the TruClient protocol.

WebDriver Sampler can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)